# Knockout nested binding in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I continue learning knockout and continue facing weird issues I don't know how to overcome.

I have the following html page and js script:

HTML:

```
<div data-bind="debug: $data, foreach: objects">
    <span hidden="hidden" data-bind="value: type.id"></span>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: type.title" />
    <button type="button" data-bind="click: $parent.removeObject">- </button>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group form-inline">
    <select data-bind="options: availableTypes, optionsValue: function(item) {return item;},
                        optionsText: function(item) {return item.title;}, value: itemToAdd.type,
                        optionsCaption: 'Select types...'"></select>
    <button type="button" data-bind="click: addObject">+</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function model() {
  var self = this;

  var types = [new Type("1"), new Type("2"), new Type("3")];
  var objects = [new Object("1")];

  self.objects = ko.observableArray(objects);

  self.usedTypes = ko.computed(function() {
    return types.filter(function(type) {
      for (var j = 0; j < self.objects().length; j++) {
        if (self.objects()[j].type.id === type.id) {
          return true;
        }
      }
      return false;
    });
  }, self);

  self.availableTypes = ko.computed(function() {
    return types.filter(function(type) {
      for (var j = 0; j < self.usedTypes().length; j++) {
        if (self.usedTypes()[j].id === type.id) {
          return false;
        }
      }
      return true;
    });
  }, self);

  self.itemToAdd = new Object();

  self.addObject = function() {
    self.objects.push(self.itemToAdd);
    self.itemToAdd = new Object();
  };

  self.removeObject = function(object) {
    self.objects.remove(object);
  };
};

function Object(type) {
  var self = this;
  self.type = new Type(type);
}

function Type(id) {
  var self = this;
  self.id = id;
  self.title = id;
}
ko.applyBindings(new model());
```

I simplified model to show the error. The thing is that knockout claims it is illegal to call do this:
`<span hidden="hidden" data-bind="value: type.id"></span>`
Because it can't find property `id` in context. As far as I can see it is there and everything ok with it.

Could, please, anybody point me at my mistakes?

p.s. Here is a [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m7vs58h7/15/)

**ADDITION**
Thanks to @Daryl's help I was able to localize the issue. If I replace

```
  self.itemToAdd = new Object();

  self.addObject = function() {
    self.objects.push(self.itemToAdd);
    self.itemToAdd = new Object();
  };
```

with:

```
  self.itemToAdd = new Object();

  self.addObject = function() {
    self.objects.push(new Object(1));
    self.itemToAdd = new Object();
  };
```

though, the following code still doesn't work:

```
  self.itemToAdd = new Object("1");

  self.addObject = function() {
    self.objects.push(self.itemToAdd);
    self.itemToAdd = new Object();
  };
```

It seems `itemToAdd` objects is populated incorrectly from html elements it's binded to. But I still don't know what exactly is wrong.

Comment: Judging from your fiddle, it seems to be loading everything properly - It's just when you try to add a new object that it complains. My guess is that it's due to how your addObject method works. You can see that it's pushing self.itemToAdd which is always initialized to be an empty Object since you're not passing the type parameter in. Since you're not passing the type parameter in, your Type object's properties are being initialized with an initial value of undefined. Try passing a "1" "2" or "3" to your Object constructor and see if it behaves how you would expect.

Comment: @Daryl, thanks for reply. I tried to do what you suggested but results are pretty strange and they don't help me to solve the issue. I'll update the post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You've allowed your type dropdown to be unset. When knockout shows the caption, it clears the actual value. This means that, by rendering the UI, your `itemToAdd.type` is cleared.

Your second approach solves this by not using the data-bound instance.

Furthermore:

- I wouldn't overwrite the `Object` constructor if I were you... Find a different name.
- Make sure your `itemToAdd` has observable properties if you want to do two-way binding to the UI.